# To find points of intersection between straight lines & our figure in matlab

Tags: matlab, intersection, edge-detection

We are doing a project on ear recognition. We have got the edges of the ear in a figure & have found the centroid of each. We have also drawn lines from the centroid at 10 degree intervals. Now we need to know how to find the points of intersection of these lines with our ear edges in matlab.

Answer (score 4):

There is great submission on MATLAB Central File Exchange to find curves intersections:

[Fast and Robust Curve Intersections](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/11837-fast-and-robust-curve-intersections)

If your ear edge represented as curve and you can calculate at least 2 points for each lines, you can find their intersections very fast with this function.

Comment: The best solutions are those someone else already implemented for you. +1 for finding it.